# About session in JPA

Tags: jpa

I wanna know how does **JPA** deals with database sessions, the **number of sessions** open by a JPA provider (for instance **hibernate**), for a database access for example, does a JPA provider save the database session that has opened to serve this request for all the upcoming request ? or it closes it and open another one for the next database access ?

I'm really confused about this concept of dealing with session in JPA and I need someone to explain it in details.

regards.

Comment: By session, you mean JDBC connection, right? If so, it does like everything else: ask a Connection to a DataSource every time it needs one. The DataSource is the one dealing with connection pooling (i.e. reuse of connections)

Comment: Thanks 4 your feedback, but my question in not about how to use session (get and instantiate object etc...), it about the number of connections that will be opened, how long does a JPA provider save db connection when serving client requests ?

Comment: JPA gets a connection from the DataSource when starting a transaction, does the job of the transaction using that connection, then closes the connection. Since the DataSource is usually a connection  pool, closing the connection simply releases the connection to the pool. The pool is the one deciding how many connections to open, and how long to keep them open. Not JPA.

Comment: The JPA implementation will have a single connection per EntityManager at any time, but it is up to the implementation whether it releases it back to the pool after the txn is committed. See the JPA spec for what restrictions are placed on the implementation

Comment: Thanks for your good explanations  Neil Stockton and JB Nizet both. It's clear now. So I have to see now how to configure conenction pool with JPA providers.

Comment: FYI: If you are using Wildfly I(we) can tell you precisely where that value is stored in the standalone.xml